# SAS format $100,000 to $100K

Tags: sas

I need to convert large numbers in $ to numbers in thousands of $ (like $100,000 to $100K)
How do I do that in SAS?

I couldn't find a specific format for that, and all examples of custom formats refer to ranges or specific values.

Here is what the PROC FORMAT has to do:

1. take the number as an input
2. divide this number by 1,000
3. add "K" at the end
4. insert commas between 3 digits as dollar format would do.

Could you please direct me on how to achieve this in SAS?

Comment: Did you try creating a custom function to use in your custom format? https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p1gg77jyhc9s42n1f1vjyx2hsg8b.htm

Comment: I would have thought the fourth example in the PROC FORMAT documentation would have been what you wanted. "Creating a Picture Format for Large Dollar Amounts" https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/n0kl9qj532rbqln187us4ao371h7.htm  If that doesn't work, please explain what you would like changed.

Comment: @Reeza - you will note there is an important difference between the doc's explanation and OP's, and it's one frankly that isn't obvious to a newer user I don't think, as much as it is obvious to me (and you, I'm sure).  Adding those commas is a bit of a step for users not used to picture formats!

Comment: To add the comma's? It's the answer I linked to but adds comma's which you've done. You've also handled numbers less than 1000 differently which isn't specified. The reason for the downvotes is no attempt is shown to answer the question.

Comment: @Reeza I disagree, actually, though I initially didn't.  The question does show research effort - the user discusses looking at specific formats and searching for custom formats.  The user didn't stumble on the answer, obviously, but it seems to me like this is as much research as can be expected for a question like this - and there's no "what I tried" in a case like this [asking about a direct feature of the language].

Comment: I guess I disagree since it is the fourth example in the PROC FORMAT documentation.  I would assume basic research would incorporate checking the manual. FYI - close vote is not mine.

Comment: I don't generally blame people for having trouble finding things in SAS documentation, even when it does seem easy... I've missed enough obvious things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picture formats do exactly what you are asking about.  You do have a slightly different requirement though from the [documentation Tom/Reeza linked](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/n0kl9qj532rbqln187us4ao371h7.htm), namely not going beyond K and adding the commas.

```
proc format;
  picture dollark
   0-999.99 = "009" (prefix='$')
   1e03-high = "000,000,009K" (prefix='$' mult=0.001)
  ;
quit;
data _null_;
  do x = 100,1000,100000,10000000,10000000000000;
    put x= dollark.;
  end;
run;
```

Note that it does *not* work for the last example, because that went past the maximum number in the picture - this is to show the limitation.  Add more 000,000,000 if you have larger amounts possible.  (0 = digit that can be left off, 9 = digit that is always displayed.)

Also, I ignore cents - this is just dollars.  Look at the documentation for more details on how to handle that if you actually *want* cents.

Comment: Thank you very much, Joe. This works great.  I'm new to SAS and I'd never think the "picture" has anything to do with currency formats.